# What does the phrase "for this purpose" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I would like another phrase instead of "for that reason."

Comment: The title and the body of the question do not agree. Which is the real question?

Answer (score 1):

If you are proposing to use "for this purpose" in place of "for that reason", then I think you will have difficulty.

My first interpretation of "for this purpose" refers to a function or a process to be carried out. I would use it in sentences such as

> When the group realised that the water needed to be filtered to remove leaves and bugs, Lisa used her new scarf for this purpose.
>
> Although candidates are permitted to bring reference material to the examination, the prescribed textbook must not be used for this purpose.

In neither case, could "that reason" be used instead.